# Saving the data of a variable until the user closes the application?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm thinking how best to save the `age` of a user from 2 Date of Birth variables: `YEAR` and `DAY_OF_YEAR`. As `age` is a dynamic variable, I want the `age` variable creation to only be called once as I don't want to have to call a function every time I want to refer to `age` in the same user session.

Then when the user closes the app and reopens, I want `age` to be initialised again incase their `age` has changed.

So how can I save `age` for the user session and then initialise it again once the app reopens?

Comment: Store the value in shared preference and when your app opens check if the age matches the one in shared preference and continue or rewrite the preference if the age is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Static" Variable

```
private static int myValue;

public static int getMyValue() {
    return myValue;
}

public static void setMyValue(int myValue) {
    MyActivity.myValue = myValue;
}
```

Static Values will only be held only as long as the app is Open

anytime you need to set new value you call setMyValue()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calculate the age in the application class and store it in shared preference, and use it wherever you want from shared preferences.
Also check in application class if calculated age and age in shared preference is same or not, if it is same no need to update preference else update shared preferences.

Suppose the name of your age calculation method is calculateAge(),

```
public class App extends Application {
  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        int age = calculateAge();
        if (a != getAge()) {
           saveAge(this, a); 
       }
    }

    int calculateAge() {
      return age;
    }

        public static void saveAge(Context context, String lang,  int age) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(quesID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("age", age);
        editor.apply();
    }


    public static int getAge(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
     context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.filename), 
         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getInt("age", 0);
    }
}
```

and to use age anywhere in app use App.getAge();

Comment: Unfortunately there are multiple age variables (for different users) so I can't really store it in sharedPref.

Comment: This is Java? This is question aimed at Kotlin.

Comment: In that case, store them in SQLite DB, and make user id as the primary key to store and fetch age details. and you could use the room for easy implementation of the same.